# Unzipping Java 3D file for Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, zip, java-3d

I have downloaded a Java 3d-1_5_1-macosx.zip. I am trying unzip the file. The file j3d-jre.zip is the file that needs to be unzipped according to the README.txt. I have moved the folder to my desktop so from the terminal I have typed cd Desktop/java3d-1_5_1-macosx-2/. Then from the terminal I type unzip j3d-jre.zip and this is what I see. *Archive:  j3d-jre.zip
replace lib/ext/j3dcore.jar? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:* I also tried using right click and stuff it. The instructions from the README file are below.

Download java3d-1_5_1-
XXX.zip to a temporary directory, for example, "/tmp"

Unzip java3d-1_5_1-XXX.zip into "/tmp" as follows:

cd /tmp
unzip java3d-1_5_1-*.zip

This will create a "java3d-1_5_1-XXX" subdirectory in /tmp where the downloaded files can be found. The file you need for manual installation is "j3d-jre.zip".

Unzip Java 3D 1.5.1 into the "jre" directory of your JDK. For example, if your JDK is in "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre", you would do the following:

cd /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre
unzip /tmp/java3d-1_5_1-*/j3d-jre.zip

Verify that the j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, and vecmath.jar files end up in "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre/lib/ext"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not simply open it with Archive Utility (right click on the file on a Mac) or download a free program such as Stuff It Expander? http://www.stuffit.com/mac-expander.html#compare?

From what I understand it looks like you have done this step a few times

> Archive: j3d-jre.zip replace lib/ext/j3dcore.jar? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll,
>   [N]one, [r]ename:

If its giving you these options then the file must be un-zipped already and is there in the folder, maybe check to see if you can find it.

> README.txt says that j3d-jre.zip is the zip file that contains the the
>   files that need to be installed. Does that necesarily mean that is the
>   file that is supposed to be unzipped?

I would say yes

Comment: I will try stuff it. But I have tried opening it with a right click and all that happens is that a copy of the lib folder is created(not sure why). Inside the lib folder is some jar files.

Comment: Ok. I tried out stuff it and the same thing happened when I unzipped the file myself. There is another library folder now with some jar files. They are j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar and vecmath.jar. I cannot open them, but I can open the web page for them, not that it does any good.

Comment: I think you need to re read the README.txt file and look at the website that you got this from. Are you sure you are following the correct instructions?

Lastly the format of your questions is really unclear. Think about the people reading them, I am still unsure of exactly what you are trying to do and i have read it 4 times. What is your overall aim?

Comment: I included the README instructions above